# permission denied virtual hosts xampp

Tags: macos, xampp, virtualhost, http-status-code-403

I am trying to load some virtual hosts on xampp with mac.

One of them gives me 403 error and the other redirects to the xampp control page no matter what directories I add onto the root virtualhost domain

domain.local = domain.local/xampp

domain.local/index.php = domain.local/xampp (there is a valid index.php)

my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
127.0.0.1       domain
127.0.0.1       domain2
```

my httpd.conf file

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/domain1">
  AllowOverride FileInfo
</Directory>

<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/domain2">
  AllowOverride FileInfo
</Directory>
```

my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
    NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin domain.local
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/domain"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/domain">
        AllowOverride All

        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin domain2.local
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/domain2"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/domain2">
        AllowOverride All

        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

location of the 2 domains:

/Applications/XAMPP/xampfiles/htdocs

Appreciate any help in the matter

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+F and search for DocumentRoot in httpd.conf file. There you should find 2 places to set your DocumentRoot up. That is the folder you have granted access to. (403 Error is for not having permission to access this folder) I'm using Windows so this is the closest I can get to solving this problem.